# How to asynchronously update a state variable with a timer?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rxjs

I am trying to render a sentence one word at a time asynchronously.

For e.g. -> "A new hope" -> render "A", "new", and "hope" with an interval of 1sec in between.

I have tried a couple of approaches (shown below) but all of them render the words unreliably (with inconsistent intervals in between the words and/or glitching words during transitions)

[Working project (Stackblitz)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-playground-practice-ygge9p?file=index.js)

Snippet of the approaches -

```
// Apprach 0 - interval
let curWordIdx = 0;
let intervalId = setInterval(() => updateText(wordList[curWordIdx++]), 1000);

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  };
});

// Approach 1 - setTimeOut
for (let index = 0; index < wordList.length; index++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    updateText(wordList[index]);
  }, index * 1000);
}

// Approach 2 - RxJS
interval(1000).pipe(
  take(wordList.length),
  map(i => wordList[i])
).subscribe({
  next: (word) => updateText(word),
  error: _ => console.log('error'),
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You you're asking on a proper solution, here you are. Each time your `sentence` is changed the process starts again. The last word is kept.

```
const RenderSentence = ({ sentence }) => {
  const [word, setWord] = useState('')
  useEffect(() => {
    const words = sentence.trim().split(/\s+/g)
    let index = 0
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setWord(words[index++])
      // Keep the last word
      if (index === words.length) {
        clearInterval(timer)
      }
    }, 1000)
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }, [sentence])
  return (
    <div className="render-canvas">
      <span>{word}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works seamlessly. 
I see that moving the setInterval() inside the useEffect() callback made the difference. Can you please explain the reason behind this? From what I understand the effect callback is only invoked once (since sentence is static). Why does it behave differently from regular statements in the top level of the function component?

Comment: Please clarify your question. That's the point that all async operations and effects must be kept inside the effect callback. Everything outside the callback is kind of declarative and must know nothing about any imperative operations. To better understand it you should learn how Fiber and its effects work from inside.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to a different approach.  You can do this entirely with CSS:

```js
const RenderSentence = ({ wordList }) => {
  return (
    <div className="render-canvas">
      {wordList.map((word, i) => (
        <span
          key={i}
          className="word animateIn"
          /* create a stagger effect */
          style={{ '--delay': i * 0.25 + 's' }}
        >
          {word}&nbsp;
        </span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
root.render(
  <RenderSentence
    wordList={'A new hope'
      .trim()
      .replace(/\s{2,}/, ' ')
      .split(' ')}
  />
);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Audiowide&display=swap');

body {
  background: black;
  color: gold;
  display: grid;
  font-family: Audiowide, san-serif;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  place-content: center;
}

.word {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 5rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.animateIn {
  animation-delay: var(--delay, 0);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-name: fadeZoomIn;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.6, 2.19);
}

@keyframes fadeZoomIn {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```